# Publishing upgrade to Android application

Tags: android, upgrade

I have an application I uploaded to the market and now I want to upload an update.

There doesn't seem to be an update button anywhere!

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Market Dashboard frontpage, navigate into your application, select the **APK files** tab. There you have the **Upload APK** button.

Comment: Do I then have to delete or disable the old one or does it do it itself?

Comment: It will replace the old APK file. Try it, its hard to do it wrong :)